# Can I defined the class that contain the struct and the struct have this class inside

Tags: c++

I have a problem with struct and class. After i compile it the show the error "forward declaration of ‘class a’

```
class a 
{     
    
    
    public:
 
    struct b
    {
        a a1;
        a a2;
    };
   
};
```

Comment: you're decalring an incomplete type inside b, this will not work

Comment: You'll need to declare `b` outside and after `a`.

Comment: @AlexF not quite, there are no `b`s in an `a`

Answer (score 3):

To define `struct b` as a definition within the context of `class a`, you can forward-declare `b` inside `a` and add the real definition afterwards:

```
class a 
{     
public:
    struct b;
};

struct a::b
{
    a a1;
    a a2;
};
```